# Place direct shortcut to folder in dock

Tags: macos, mac, dock

I am using Mac OSX El Capitan (version 10.11.5) for the first time (I have never used a Mac before, but am familiar with Windows).

I want to add a shortcut to a folder in the dock, but all I can do is add a "button" that I have to click to then open a menu where one of the entries is "Open in Finder".

Can I place a shortcut (or button, or whatever it may be called) in the dock that, when clicked (left-clicked), opens the given folder in a Finder window, without extra steps?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out on Mac OS you cannot drag a folder to the Dock to create a shortcut.

You have to first create an "alias" and then drag that alias to the Dock.